# Реакт не рендерит код, который обернут компонентом

Tags: reactjs

У меня имеется такой компонент кнопки:

```
import React from "react";
import classnames from 'classnames';

function Button({cart, outline, add, black, circle, delimiter, cartBottom, OnClick}) {


   return (
      <button className={classnames('button', {
            'button--cart': cart,
            'button--outline': outline,
            'button--add': add,
            'button--black': black,
            'button--circle': circle,
            'button__delimiter': delimiter,
            'cart_bottom-buttons': cartBottom
         }
      )}
              onClick={OnClick}>
      </button>
   )
}

export default Button
```

И вот кусок где я ее использую

```
<Button add outline>
               <svg
                  width="12"
                  height="12"
                  viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
               >
                  <path
                     d="M10.8 4.8H7.2V1.2C7.2 0.5373 6.6627 0 6 0C5.3373 0 4.8 0.5373 4.8 1.2V4.8H1.2C0.5373 4.8 0 5.3373 0 6C0 6.6627 0.5373 7.2 1.2 7.2H4.8V10.8C4.8 11.4627 5.3373 12 6 12C6.6627 12 7.2 11.4627 7.2 10.8V7.2H10.8C11.4627 7.2 12 6.6627 12 6C12 5.3373 11.4627 4.8 10.8 4.8Z"
                     fill="white"
                  />
               </svg>
               <span>Добавить</span>
               <i>2</i>
            </Button>
```

Рендерится кнопка с правильными классами, но все что обернуто этим компонентом не рендерится, то есть у меня рендерится пустая кнопка с классами `<button class="button button--outline button--add"></button>` подскажите почему так получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `<Button />` необходимо добавить рендер `children`, которые получаем из прос от Реакта. Получается примрено так:

```js
// import React from "react";
// import classnames from "classnames";

function Button({
  cart,
  outline,
  add,
  black,
  circle,
  delimiter,
  cartBottom,
  OnClick,
  children, // добавлено children
}) {
  return (
    <button onClick={OnClick}>
      {children}  {/*добавлено children*/}
    </button>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>
        <span>Добавить</span>
        <i>2</i>        
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```